# 2D pointer array to 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I convert

```
char *s[]={
           "to err is human",
           "but to really mess things up ",
           "one needs to know c!!"
           };
```

to

```
char s[3][50]={
           "to err is human",
           "but to really mess things up ",
           "one needs to know c!!"
           };
```

Comment: What part of the given declarations are unclear to you? What have you tried? Also, it isn't really clear what you mean by convert. Do you want to copy the data from the first variable into the second in runtime, or are you trying to rewrite the code but can't get it working?

Comment: i want to copy the data in the runtime

Comment: Post your attempt at doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *s[]={
        "to err is human",
        "but to really mess things up ",
        "one needs to know c!!"
    };
    int i, size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s);
    char ns[size][50];//or use malloc, E.g next line
    //char (*ns)[50] = calloc(size, sizeof(char[50]));
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        memset(ns[i], 0, 50);//unnecessary if you use the calloc
        strcpy(ns[i], s[i]);
        //printf("%s\n", ns[i]);
    }
/*
    char ns[3][50]= {
        "to err is human",
        "but to really mess things up ",
        "one needs to know c!!"
    };
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really already is, just drop the [3] subscript for []:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char s[][50]={
        "to err is human",
        "but to really mess things up ",
        "one needs to know c!!"
        };

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf ("s [%d]  %s\n", i, s[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

output:

```
s [0]  to err is human
s [1]  but to really mess things up
s [2]  one needs to know c!!
```

Your original `char *s[]={` will also work.

Answer (score -1):

No need to remember Size of array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

char *s[]={
        "to err is human",
        "but to really mess things up ",
        "one needs to know c!!",
        '\0'
        };
    int i = 0;
    char SA[100][100];
    while (s[i]  != '\0') {
        strcpy(SA[i],s[i]);
        i++;
        }
                    SA[i]='\0'
    printf("SA[1][1] : %c\n",SA[1][1])  ;
    return 0;

}
```

Output

```
 SA[1][1] : u (as expected)
```

Comment: No need to allocate 100,000 bytes when you only have need for 150 bytes. Unless of course, you like stack overflow.

Comment: @Lundin as of i can see he didn't asked with memory constraint. If this is the situation i just  twick code a bit. My expectation was, Coder doesn't have to bother for the size of Output array.